# awk/sed replace multiple newlines in the record except end of record

Tags: awk, sed, newline

I have file where:

- field delimiter is `\x01`
- the record delimiter is `\n`

Some lines contain multiple newlines I need to remove them, however I don't want to remove the legitimate newlines at the end of each lines. I have tried this with awk:

```
awk -F '\x01' 'NF < 87 {getline s; $0 = $0 s} 1' infile > outfile
```

But this is only working when the line contains one newline in the record (except end of line newline). This does not work for multiple newlines.

Note: the record contains 87 fields.

What am I doing wrong here?

### Example of file:

```
PL^ANov-21^A29-11-2021^A0^A00^A00^A0000000
test^A00000000
 Test^A^A^A^A
PL^ANov-21^A29-11-2021^A0^A00^A00^A0000000
test^A00000000
 Test^A^A^A^A
SL^ANov-21^A30-11-2021^AB^A0000^A1234567^A00000
test^A12102120^A00000^A00^A^A
```

NOTE: The file contains 11 fields; field separate `\x01`; record separator `\n`

### Expected result:

```
PL^ANov-21^A29-11-2021^A0^A00^A00^A0000000test^A00000000 Test^A^A^A^A
PL^ANov-21^A29-11-2021^A0^A00^A00^A0000000test^A00000000 Test^A^A^A^A
SL^ANov-21^A30-11-2021^AB^A0000^A1234567^A00000test^A12102120^A00000^A00^A^A
```

Note: I need to preserve the field delimiter (`\x01`) and record delimiter (`\n`)

Thank you very much in advance for looking into this.

The file always contains 87 fields;
The fild delimiter is '\x01', but when viewing in Linux it is represented as '^A'
Some lines contain newlines - I need to remove them, but I don't want to remove the legitimate newlines at the end of each line.
The newline appears twice in the 1st and second record and once in third record - this are the newlines I want to remove.

In the examples/expected results there are 11 delimiters "x01" represented as "^A",
I expect to have 3 records and not 6, i.e.:

1. First record:

test^A00000000 should be joined to the previous line

Test^A^A^A^A should be joined to the first line as well

forming one record:

PL^ANov-21^A29-11-2021^A0^A00^A00^A0000000test^A00000000 Test^A^A^A^A

2. Second record

test^A00000000 should be joined to the previous line

Test^A^A^A^A should be joined to that previous line as well

forming one record:

PL^ANov-21^A29-11-2021^A0^A00^A00^A0000000test^A00000000 Test^A^A^A^A

3. Third record:

test^A12102120^A00000^A00^A^A should be joined to the previous line

forming one record:

SL^ANov-21^A30-11-2021^AB^A0000^A1234567^A00000test^A12102120^A00000^A00^A^A

Note:
The example of awk - provided works when there is one unwanted newline in the record  but not when there are multiple newlines

Thank you so very much. It works perfectly. Thank you for explaining it so well to me too.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts, please post samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you

Comment: for sample purposes we do not need to see 87 fields; you should be able to demonstrate the issue with 4-5 fields (each no more than 5-10 characters each), and perhaps 5-10 lines (some with single newline, some with multiple newlines)

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. May I suggest that you take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)?

Comment: Do your input files always contain a multiple of 87 fields? If not, you need to add an information to your question: what do you want to do with the remaining fields? Please answer by editing your question, not in comments.

Comment: Your example of input and expected result are not consistent. 1) what are these `^`? Do they represent the field separator? If yes, please edit your question and use only this one instead of `\x01` (invisible) and `^`. When you will have received an answer it will be easy to adapt. 2) In your expected result you concatenate the last field of an input record and the first field of the next (`A0000000test`). Is it really what you want? 3) You mention 11 fields but there 12 `^`-separated fields in your expected result. Is it an error? Please answer by editing your question, not in comments.

Comment: You write: "_Some lines contain multiple newlines I need to remove them, however I don't want to remove the legitimate newlines at the end of each lines_". This does not really make sense. By definition a line contains only one newline, at the end. Please clarify by editing your question, not in comments.

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of why your attempt does not work as you expect, and for a working solution. As you know how to define the fields separator (`-F'\x01`) why don't you simplify your question by using a visible one, for instance `|`? And why don't you use only the 12 fields example, instead of mixing 87 and 12? I strongly suggest that you learn how to format your question with markdown (see my other comment for the link), and that you modify your question with **only** 12 fields and **only** `|` as fields separator. It will become clear and easy to answer.

Comment: And, by the way, you know [what to do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), don't you?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/\x01/&/87;Ta;s/\n//g' file
```

Gather up lines until there are 87 separators, remove any newlines and print the result.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with your attempt is that you concatenate two lines, print the result and move to the next line. `NF` is then reset to the next fields count. As all your lines have less than 87 fields the `NF < 87` condition is useless, your script would work the same without it.

Try this `awk` script:

```sh
$ awk -F'\x01' -vn=87 -vi=0 '
    {printf("%s", $0); i+=NF; if(i==n) {i=0; print "";} else i-=1;}' file
```

Here, we use the real `\x01` field separator and the `NF` fields count. Variable `i` counts the number of already printed fields. We first print the current line without the trailing newline (`printf("%s", $0)`). Then we update our `i` fields counter. If it is equal to `n` we reset it and print a newline. Else we decrement it such that we do not count the last field of this line and the first of the next as 2 separate fields.

Demo with `n=12` instead of 87 and your own input file (with `\x01` field separators):

```sh
$ awk -F'\x01' -vn=12 -vi=0 '
    {printf("%s", $0); i+=NF; if(i==n) {i=0; print "";} else i-=1;}' file |
  sed 's/\x01/|/g'
PL|Nov-21|29-11-2021|0|00|00|0000000test|00000000 Test||||
PL|Nov-21|29-11-2021|0|00|00|0000000test|00000000 Test||||
SL|Nov-21|30-11-2021|B|0000|1234567|00000test|12102120|00000|00||
```

The `sed` command shows the result with the `\x01` replaced by `|` for easier viewing.